# Jquery Ui sortable, I cannot drop an item to be the last element in my sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I cannot seem to be able to get jquery UI sortable to let me drop my item below the last item in my list. It always pops up to the 2nd to last. I wondered if anyone else has encountered this, or has any suggestions.

[image]

Here i am dropping my 'watch a video' field down below the 'facebook like button' field and jquery ui seems to think i want to put it above the 'facebook like button', and when i drop it, it does go above it.

```
$( ".availableEntriesWrapper").sortable({
                        forcePlaceholderSize: false,
                        helper: function(e,li) {
                            copyHelper= li.clone().insertAfter(li);
                            return li.clone();
                        },
                        handle: '.entryFieldTitle',
                        connectWith: ".mandatoryEntriesWrapper.sortable, .bonusEntriesWrapper.sortable",
                        revert: 300,
                        cancel: '.disabled',
                        tolerance: "intersect",
                        distance: 10,
                        stop: function( event, ui ) {
                            var element = ui.item;
                            copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
                            bonusEntries.createBonusEntry(element);
                        },
                        over: function( event, ui ) {
                            console.log(event);
                            console.log(ui);
                        },
                        out: function( event, ui ) {
                        } 
                    });
```

here is my jquery ui instantiation code

```
video_watch: function(bonus, where){
            if(!bonus.id) bonus = {id:0, type: "video_watch", text : "Watch this Video", data:"", data_2:"", data_3:"", points: 1, prechecked:0, required: 0, repeatable:1};
            var element = $('<li class="'+where+'Entry entryField '+bonus.type+'" data-id="'+bonus.id+'" data-type="'+bonus.type+'">'+
                                '<span class="entryFieldTitle"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>&nbsp; Watch a Video <div class="hover_popup"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div></span>'+
                                '<div class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>'+
                                '<div class="configurationOptions">'+
                                    '<div class="fieldInput"><span class="input_label">Label: </span><input type="text" class="entry_text" value="'+bonus.text+'" placeholder="label"></div>'+
                                    '<div class="fieldInput"><span class="input_label">Youtube Video Id:   </span><input type="text" class="entry_data" value="'+bonus.data+'"      placeholder="VTO5yiN1b-I   "></div>'+
                                    //'<div class="fieldInput"><span class="input_label">   </span><input type="text" class="entry_data_2" value="'+bonus.data_2+'"     placeholder="   "></div>'+
                                    '<div class="fieldInput points_input"><span class="input_label">Extra Entries:   </span><input type="number" class="entry_points" value="'+bonus.points+'"></div>'+
                                    '<div class="advancedSettings">'+
                                        '<div class="bonusSetting required_setting"><input type="checkbox" class="required"         '+((bonus.required==1) ? 'checked' : '')+'><span>Required For Entry?</span><br/></div>'+
                                        '<div class="bonusSetting repeatable_setting editable"><input type="checkbox" class="repeatable"    '+((bonus.repeatable==1) ? 'checked' : '')+'><span>Only once per contest/user?</span></div>'+
                                        (App.isManager ? '<div class="bonusSetting restricted_setting"><input type="checkbox" class="restricted"        '+((bonus.restricted==1) ? 'checked' : '')+'></span> Restricted To Corporate</span></div>' : '') +
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<span class="entryInfo repeating">repeating</span>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</li>');
            return element;
```

And here is a sample of the list item I am dropping, which may or may  not be relevant. They are all basically the same

The ul html is pretty plain, all the fields are simply appended into it

```
<ul class="mandatoryEntriesWrapper sortable fieldsWrapper"></ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `forceHelperSize:true` ??? also I would suggest using the helper to give a visual queue as to where you are dropping the item.

Comment: also look into `forcePlaceholderSize` as well ... these are like hacks because sometimes the width and height collapses (become 0px) so that's to combat that